# How are Qt uint types serialized?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using QDataStream to serialize some uint variables. A few examples of values and its corresponding output:

```
quint32 i;

i = 99
[0,0,0,99]

i = 255
[0,0,0,255]

i = 256
[0,0,1,0]

i = 510
[0,0,1,254]

i = 512
[0,0,2,0]

i = 1024
[0,0,4,0]
```

How is this conversion done?

Here's what I used to print the output.

```
QByteArray barr;
QDataStream stream(&barr,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);

quint32 i32 = 512;

stream << i32;

QList<int> valueList;
for(int i = 0 ; i < barr.count() ; ++i)
    valueList.append(QChar(barr.at(i)).unicode());

qDebug() << valueList;
```

Comment: how did you print the output?

Comment: I've added the code I used to print the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like standard [big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) representation. This is how integers are actually broken into bytes in computer memory. For example:

```
510 = 0 * (1 << 24) + 0 * (1 << 16) + 1 * (1 << 8) + 254
```

The reverse order of bytes, little-endian, is more popular nowadays. You make a choice with [QDataStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdatastream-members.html).setByteOrder().

Here is the code that splits a 32-bit integer into bytes:

```
void putUint32BigEndian(quint32 x)
{
     putByte(x >> 24);
     putByte((x >> 16) & 0xff);
     putByte((x >> 8) & 0xff);
     putByte(x & 0xff);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

Apparently

```
xi = (quint8 )(X >> (8*i))
```

Where `X` is the original `quint32`,`i` the byte index and `xi` the ith digit in the output you provided. The serialization they perform is as simple as

```
quint8* data = (quint8*)(&X);
```

or

```
unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*)(&X);
xi = data[i]
```

Serialization does depend on endianness. That's why `QDataStream` has [properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html#ByteOrder-enum) such as

- `QDataStream::ByteOrder`
- `QDataStream::FloatingPointPrecision`

Comment: This answer is misleading. First, `>>` shifts by bits, not bytes. Second, treating an int as a byte array gives different results depending on endianess.

Comment: serialization ***does*** depend on the endianess. I indeed made a mistake about the bitshifts

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an index based encoding multiplied with 256 added downwards. I'll show you the "big" numbers from the list.

```
i = 510
[0,0,1,254]

510 = 1 * 256 + 254

i = 512
[0,0,2,0]

512 = 2* 256 + 0
```

Following the logic it's easy to see the pattern ...